# req.body giving an empty object {} only in case of api/vi/user/login route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

`req.body` is empty in Node.js Express API route when sending JSON request using Postman.

This is the error:

```
<pre>Error: Username or email is required<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at file:///C:/Users/hrshl/OneDrive/Desktop/Harshal/Web%20dev/vdeohub-backend/src/controllers/user.controller.js:117:15</pre>
```

This part is causing the error:

```
if (!username && !email) {
        throw new ApiError(400, 'Username or email is required');
}
```

This is the `loginUser` function which was giving the error:

```js
const loginUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    // Take the data from the frontend - username/email and password
    // Validate the user details - if all fields are present or not
    // Check if the username/email exists in database
    // If yes, check if the password is correct or not using isPasswordCorrect method
    // create an access token and a refresh token+
    const generateAccessAndRefreshTokens = async (userId) => {
        try {
            user = User.findById(userId);
            const accessToken = user.generateAccessToken();
            const refreshToken = user.generateRefreshToken();

            user.refreshToken = refreshToken;
            user.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });

            return { accessToken, refreshToken };
        } catch (error) {
            return new ApiError(
                500,
                'Something went wrong while generating access and refresh tokens'
            );
        }
    };

    const { username, email, password } = req.body;

    // console.log(req.body);    

    if (!username && !email) {
        throw new ApiError(400, 'Username or email is required');            //error from here
    }

    const user = await User.findOne({
        $or: [{ username }, { email }],
    });

    if (!user) {
        return new ApiError(404, 'User does not exists');
    }

    if (!password) {
        return new ApiError(400, 'Password is required');
    }

    const isPasswordValid = user.isPasswordCorrect(password);

    if (!isPasswordValid) {
        throw new ApiError(401, 'Invalid user credentials');
    }

    const { accessToken, refreshToken } = await generateAccessAndRefreshTokens(
        user._id
    );

    const loggedInUser = User.findById(user._id).select(
        '-password -refreshToken'
    );

    options = {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
    };
    

    return res
        .status(200)
        .cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, options)
        .cookie('accessToken', accessToken, options)
        .json(
            new ApiResponse(
                200,
                { user: loggedInUser, accessToken, refreshToken },
                'User logged in successfully'
            )
        );
});
```

This is the `asyncHandler` utility:

```js
const asyncHandler = (requestHandler) => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        Promise.resolve(requestHandler(req, res, next)).catch((err) =>
            next(err)
        );
    };
};

export { asyncHandler };
```

If you need to look at the entire codebase, head to my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/harshalgunjal69/vdeohub-backend).

There is also a `registerUser` function, and it also takes in arguments from `req.body`, but that one works perfectly fine:

```js
const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    // get user details from frontend
    // validate the user details - if all the fields are present or not
    // check if user already exixts in database - username, email
    // if user exists send error response to frontend
    // check if the user has uploaded a profile picture/avatar
    // if yes, upload the image to cloudinary
    // check for the image uploaded to cloudinary successfully or not
    // if yes, save the user details to a new user object
    // create a new user in the database
    // remove the password and the refreshToken from the response
    // check for user creation success or failure
    // if success, send the response to the frontend

    const { fullName, email, username, password } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body);

    if (
        [fullName, email, username, password].some(
            (field) => field?.trim() === ''
        )
    ) {
        throw new ApiError(400, 'All fields are required');
    }

    const existedUser = await User.findOne({
        $or: [{ email }, { username }],
    });

    if (existedUser) {
        throw new ApiError(409, 'User already exists');
    }

    console.log(req.files);

    const avatarLocalPath = req.files?.avatar[0]?.path;
    const coverImageLocalPath = req.files?.coverImage?.[0]?.path;

    if (!avatarLocalPath) {
        throw new ApiError(
            400,
            'Avatar is required. Avatar not found in request body'
        );
    }

    const avatar = await uploadToCloudinary(avatarLocalPath);

    let coverImage;
    if (!(coverImageLocalPath === undefined)) {
        coverImage = await uploadToCloudinary(coverImageLocalPath);
    }

    if (!avatar) {
        throw new ApiError(
            400,
            'Avatar is required. Failed to upload avatar to cloudinary'
        );
    }

    const user = await User.create({
        fullName: fullName,
        email: email,
        username: username.toLowerCase(),
        password: password,
        avatar: avatar.url,
        coverImage: coverImage?.url || '',
    });

    const createdUser = await User.findById(user._id).select(
        '-password -refreshToken'
    );

    if (!createdUser) {
        throw new ApiError(500, 'Failed to create user. Something went wrong.');
    }

    return res
        .status(201)
        .json(new ApiResponse(200, createdUser, 'User created successfully'));
});
```

I tried console logging the entire request, and it was fine, just the `request.body` was empty. I also tried adding bodyparser, but it didn't do anything. I also tried changing the check to:

```
if (!(username || email)) {
        throw new ApiError(400, 'Username or email is required');
}
```

but still no luck.

Comment: Please give a [mre]. You would find that easier if your code was better factored - accessing the DB in the transport layer is very bad practice.

Comment: oh ok, sorry about that. Btw can you solve this problem?

Comment: You're probably didn't register the [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.built-in) to actually parse the body of the request, but it's impossible to tell because you didn't post that code.

Comment: I've added these:
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50kb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '50kb' }));

Comment: Can you post your indes.js code or whatever you named it, please?

Comment: You can see the entire codebase in the github repo: https://github.com/harshalgunjal69/vdeohub-backend

Comment: @YUSOFKHAN Thisi is the index.js file : https://github.com/harshalgunjal69/vdeohub-backend/blob/main/src/index.js

Comment: Try to replace app.use(
    cors({
        origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN,
        credentials: true,
    })
); 

with app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true }));
This change allows any origin and still sends credentials like cookies or headers. If this resolves the issue, the problem lies with your CORS configuration.



Also add app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Headers:', req.headers);
    console.log('Body:', req.body);
    next();
});
 after app.use(cookieParser());
This can help you verify that the body is being received as expected.

Comment: I have the CORS_ORIGIN set to * in th env file.

Comment: @YUSOFKHAN Would I still need to change?

Comment: Check this file please, https://file.io/RkdzozoNvnlx

Comment: Just copy and paste the code, and let me know what was the output in the console please.

Comment: are you using postman ??

Comment: We can't solve the problem without a MRE, hence the request for one (also a basic premise of [ask]). I'm not combing through your whole repo for it, not least because then if I _do_ solve the problem that information is less discoverable for the next person which is the whole point of SO. So don't apologise, _[edit] to improve_.

Comment: @YUSOFKHAN It is showing that port 8000 is already in use, and even if i change th eport or run npx kill-port 8000, it still shows the same error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Alright, I'll edit it in just 10 min

Comment: @YUSOFKHAN I fixed the bug, app.listen() was written two times. But the problem mentioned in the question is stilll not solved.

This time I got this error:
<pre>Error: Username or email is required<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at file:///C:/Users/hrshl/OneDrive/Desktop/Harshal/Web%20dev/vdeohub-backend/src/controllers/user.controller.js:117:15<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at file:///C:/Users/hrshl/OneDrive/Desktop/Harshal/Web%20dev/vdeohub-backend/src/utils/asyncHandler.js:16:25<br>

Comment: You forgot to include the json request you sent with postman that caused this problem.

Comment: Yeah, Thank u very much for your response. Can't believe I did such a mistake .